# Declaration syntax error

Tags: c++

Не могу найти, что я забыл, в упор не вижу:

Ошибка:

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(11): E2141 Declaration syntax error
```

Shape.h:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef ShapeH
#define ShapeH
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Shape
{
  private:
    double radius;

  public:
    Shape(double=0);

    void setRadius(double);
    double getRadius();
}
#endif
```

Shape.cpp:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Unit1.h"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

Shape::Shape(double radius){
  this->radius = radius;
}

void Shape::setRadius(double radius){
  this->radius = radius;
}
double Shape::getRadius(){
  return radius;
}
```

Unit1.cpp:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Shape.h"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1; // <-- сюда показывает
int count = 0;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
...
```

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться с тем как создать [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точку с запятой после объявления класса.